# How to get product collection in controller in Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, product-collection

I am creating a new module in magento2 and in controller file, I try to get product collection in controller index.php file so how can I get product collection in Magento 2. so give me suggestion to sort it fast.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overview of getting product collection in Magento 2

Step 1: Declare in Vendor_ModuleName Block

Step 2: Display product collection in phtml file

..

Step 1: Declare in Vendor_ModuleName Block

You will use a block class of the module Vendor_ModuleName, then possibly inject the object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` in the constructor of the module’s block class.

```
app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/ProductCollection.php
```

add code this code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollections()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

You can request the number of the product collection, that is a limited or unlimited number.

Step 2: Display product collection in phtml file

Print out the product collection in phtml file with the below code:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollections();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

If that you have any queries about the article or any questions in general, use the comment section below!

Comment: Thank you @Baharuni Asif

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below code in your controller file:**

```
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function yourMethod()
{

    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($productCollection as $product){
         echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName();
    }  
}
```

Hope It will help you!